# mingw gcc 'TIME_UTC' undeclared

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I am compiling a program meant for the Unix-like OS to windows with msys2 using GCC

program source: [repository of the program](https://github.com/jdah/minecraft-weekend),

then this error popped up,

```
src/gfx/../util/time.h:12:27: error: 'TIME_UTC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'TIME_H'?

   12 |         timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
      |                           TIME_H
```

How do I fix this

also here is my MakeFile:

```
UNAME_S = $(shell uname -s)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-color
CFLAGS += -Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-gnu-statement-expression
CFLAGS += -Wno-gnu-compound-literal-initializer -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments
CFLAGS += -Ilib/cglm/include -Ilib/glad/include -Ilib/glfw/include -Ilib/stb -Ilib/noise -lrt # -fbracket-depth=1024
LDFLAGS = lib/glad/src/glad.o lib/cglm/libcglm.a lib/glfw/src/libglfw3.a lib/noise/libnoise.a -lm

# GLFW required frameworks on OSX
ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
    LDFLAGS += -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -framework Cocoa
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Linux)
    LDFLAGS += -ldl -lpthread
endif

SRC  = $(wildcard src/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/**/*.c)
OBJ  = $(SRC:.c=.o)
BIN = bin

.PHONY: all clean

all: dirs libs game

libs:
    cd lib/cglm && cmake . -DCGLM_STATIC=ON -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe && make
    cd lib/glad && $(CC) -o src/glad.o -Iinclude -c src/glad.c
    echo GLFW
    cd lib/glfw && cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe . && make
    cd lib/noise && make
    echo noice

dirs:
    mkdir -p ./$(BIN)

run: all
    $(BIN)/game

game: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN)/game $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJ)
```

this is the modified time.h file

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TIME_UTC time(NULL)

#define NS_PER_SECOND (1000000000)
#define NS_PER_MS (1000000)
    int NOW(){
        struct timespec ts;
        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        return ((ts.tv_sec * NS_PER_SECOND) + ts.tv_nsec);
    }

#endif
```

Enviorment:

get windows 10
install msys2
install boost from the zip onto the C++ include(not related but, just a heads up)
run the mingw64 shell
git clone the included link
edit the time.h in the src/util with the code
edit the Makefile with the posted one

Comment: Code must be in the question and not as an external link. And it needs to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not just a full code dump. In this case it would seem to be a simple matter for you to produce a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: "edit the time.h in the src/util" hmmm ... you may be breaking the *magic of standard headers*

Comment: The msys2/mingw build of gcc doesn't seem to support these C features. You might try using clock_gettime instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to measure some delay in your program. You probably don't want to use UTC for that. What if the user changes the clock during your measurement? It is better to use "monotonic time" or "boottime" for that, depending on your needs, or what your OS supports. Oh, and a second in UTC may sometimes actually have a duration of 2 or 0 seconds.

Comment: this program is originally meant for Linux and Unix like OS and I am trying to get it to be ported to windows

Comment: MSYS2 now has a UCRT64 environment where TIME_UTC is defined.